# Regex Repeating Pattern

Tags: c#, regex, split

Say you have a `string`:

```
string s = "GameObject.Find(\"obj\").GetComponent(\"comp\").GetMethod(\"method\").Get...";
```

The `string` can have any number of `GetX()` methods appended to it.

And you need to separate each method without the "." separator. Although, `GameObject.Find` can keep the `(dot)`.

Here is my code so far :

```
Match match = Regex.Match(s, "(.+?\\(\".+?\"\\))(?:\\.??)*");
```

This produces only one group. What is the correct solution to this problem?

**Edit** :

Updated with non-capturing group.

Comment: rather than that way, split the string where the token is ')'. Ignore the last substring, then add ')' to the end of every substring, and remove the '.' in the first character of every sunstring except the first substring.

Comment: That works well. I'm wondering if manual calculations like these are more or less efficient than Regex?

Comment: I don't know about performance constraints, but my solution will definitely reduce the readability of your program.

Comment: If it were in PHP I would use `~(?<=\.).+?\((\\\").+?\1\)~` I'm not sure if it means anything in the C# world, though.

Comment: I would recommend to `Match` only the `GameObject.Find` with `Regex` and seperate it from the `string`...`.Split` the new `string` with `'.'` and you can get the array of the `Methods`!

Answer (score 1):

First I'd recommend using verbatim string literals for writing regular expressions in C#. This cuts down the number of backslashes you need to write.

```
 @"(.+?\("".+?""\)\.??)*"
```

To get all the captures, inspect [`Match.Captures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures).

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/MJm4R)

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work with that, or my updated pattern "(.+?\\(\".+?\"\\))(?:\\.??)*". Match.Captures still shows a count of 1 with the input string "GameObject.Find(\"go\").GetComponent(\"Comp\")".